# Which array-position do the values go?

Tags: arrays, vba, vb.net

In which element of the array will the values stored?
If Custno is 1 then the function (getArticleCustomer) give a value back for the array ArtNo - but the element-position is not given

```
Dim ArtNo(99,3)
plNr = request.form("pricelist")
CustNo = request.form("customer")
SuppNo = request.form("supplier")

If CustNo > 0 Then
    ArtNo = getArticleCustomer(CustNo, recordArray(1))
End If
If SuppNo > 0 Then
    ArtNo = getArticleSupplier(SuppNo, recordArray(1))
End If
If CustNo = 0 And SuppNo = 0 Then
    ArtNo = getArticle(recordArray(1))
End If
```

Comment: Can you specify what `getArticleCustomer`, `getArticleSupplier` and `getArticle` are?

Comment: each of these functions return an array

Comment: Then it makes no sense to speak about element position. The assignment overrides `ArtNo` with the array returned by the given function.

Comment: Option Strict, which should be On, will not allow you to declare an array without a type.